# Using "When" in a Django annotation, with a many-to-many relationship, returns more rows than it should

Tags: django, orm, duplicates, annotations, many-to-many

I have three models defined like this:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Interface(models.Model):
    internal_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    index = models.IntegerField()
    equipment = models.ForeignKey("Equipament", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Event(models.Model):
    equipment = models.ForeignKey("Equipment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When an Event is created, it may have an index, but it also may not. This index refer to the index of the Interface.

```
events = Event.objects.all()
events = events.annotate(interface_ip=Case(
        When(Q(index__isnull=False) & Q(equipment__interface__index=F('index')), then=F('equipment__interface__internal_ip')),
        output_field=models.GenericIPAddressField()
    ))
```

When I apply this annotation, the events get multiplied by the interfaces the equipment has. This makes sense, because it's evaluating which interfaces, in the given equipment, match the index specified by `F('index')`.
How can I simply exclude the ones that don't match?

From my point of view, `Q(equipment__interface__index=F('index'))` should compare if the interface__index equals the index, and jump if it doesn't (on the other hand, I know it makes sense, since it has a default value of None, when it doesn't match).

I wish I'd have control over how the Events get inserted on the table, but unfortunately I don't, since it's an external system making direct inserts on the MySQL database, and they simply get the index and throw it in the "index" field.

Comment: You just need to filter before annotating. Also I would say this is a pretty weird query (matching `index` this way), there should be some proper relation between these two tables if they are related in some way. (Perhaps instead of a foreign key from event to equipment a foreign key from event to interface)

Comment: Adding events.filter() removes all events that don't have an index. 

I want to preserve the `.count()` of events, only adding the annotation `interface_ip`. So I can later call `.values()` and get None for those that don't match the criteria above, and the IP of the Interface for those that match. Think of it like a "virtual column" from a table, since using @property makes it hit the database once for every record when accessing.

I completely agree, this is a weird query, having an Interface associated with the event would be ideal. But these get inserted by an external system.